# How to Protect an HTML element from it's respective assigned CSS

Tags: html, css

Well I wish to know how one can avoid a specific html element from getting styled by the default assigned CSS to it. Let me explain with an example:

Suppose I have an image element with it's respective default CSS assigned to it (img{}) but if I want a particular image element like logo or social icons from getting the default CSS styling then what should I do?

I know of ID's being used to target specific elements in CSS but I wish to know if their is any other way of doing this using some special markup or CSS or use of the wrapped elements like div to overcome default values. Many Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: You can just override the defaults on the particular element you want...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what about psuedo elements?

Comment: What do you mean by “the default assigned CSS”? What do you think that might include for `img` for example?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela hmm for example lets say links have their default css properties like hover,click etc then when creating a custom navigation bar my default color codes set for nav links get override by the default css of the site.

Comment: So you are not referring to default values at all (values used by browsers when author or user style sheets assign no values), but to some general settings in some site-wide style sheets?

Comment: Hmm yes ! I think I got it all mixed up . O.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to prevent CSS rules with a selector that matches an element from applying to that element.

The best you can do is write more specific rules to override them with different values. You could, in browsers that support it, use [the initial keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial).

Comment: couldn't I use CSS psuedo codes for the elements to overcome defaults just read about it in the info btw that article was really helpful. :)

Comment: I can't see why you would think that a pseudo-class or a pseudo-element might help you with this problem.

Comment: Well I thought if I can provide a different CSS for the pseudo class then I would be able to override the default styling for certain specific elements. Correct me If I am mixing up something.

Comment: A selector that included an extra psuedo-class but was otherwise identical to the selector providing the undesired styling would be more specific (as mentioned in the second paragraph of this answer). There are usually easier ways to make a more specific selector though (since psuedo-classes are highly situational).

Comment: Alright I get it now ! Hmm thanks I learned something awesome today ! :D

Comment: I don’t see how `initial` relates to the issue.